# How to make a method common and call from shared service file into service using angular15

Tags: javascript, angular

i am using angular15 and here i need to generate unique id, so the process works perfectly fine, when i add set of code in that respective service file, but as that set of code is used across all service branches, i created a method under shared service and trying to get that data but i get as undefined.

shared.service.ts:

```
       public generateUniqueId() {
        return uuid();
       }
    
       generateCorrelationId(routerEvent:any,route:string):any {
        let previousUrl:any =[];
        let uniqueCorrelationId = '';
        routerEvent.events
        .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
        .subscribe(({urlAfterRedirects}: NavigationEnd) => {
          previousUrl.splice(0,previousUrl.length-1)
          previousUrl = [...previousUrl, urlAfterRedirects];
          if(previousUrl.length === 1 && previousUrl[0]=== route) {
            return uniqueCorrelationId = this.generateUniqueId();
          } else if(previousUrl.length == 2 && previousUrl[1] === previousUrl[0]) {
            return uniqueCorrelationId
          } else if(previousUrl.length == 2 && previousUrl[1] != previousUrl[0]) {
            return uniqueCorrelationId = this.generateUniqueId();
          } else {
            return uniqueCorrelationId;
          }
        });
      }
```

component.service.ts:

```
    constructor(private geneateUUid:GenerateUniqueIdService) {
      let uniqueIdGeneration = this.geneateUUid.generateCorrelationId(this.router,'/findprofile');
      console.log(uniqueIdGeneration,"uniqueIdGeneration")
    }
```

Observation:
in Console, first component console value comes and next respective console under shared service appears.
also here based on particular component service hit, i am checking for generation of new key or retaining it, is it possible to do it dynamically i mean as a common checking whether previous and current routing is matching.

Comment: You don't return anything, therefore it is undefined.

Comment: It should return uniqueCorrelationId

Comment: This is the problem with using return type of "any". It allows bugs to sneak thru since you don't use strong typing. You have a subscribe which eventually "returns" something, but doesn't send it anywhere. Your generateCorrelationId method doesn't return anything. If you change your return type from any to string (which is the type of return you are expecting) this will start to lead you in the right direction.

Comment: when i made that as string, A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value. this error is encountered

Comment: exactly. You are not returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

As stated you aren't returning anything. Personally, I would use `await` to make the code more readable.

Try this:

```
async generateCorrelationId(routerEvent:any,route:string): Promise<string> {
  let previousUrl:any =[];
  let uniqueCorrelationId = '';

  const navigationEnd: NavigationEnd = await new Promise((resolve) => {
    routerEvent.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
      first() // wait for the first NavigationEnd event
    ).subscribe(resolve);
  });

  previousUrl.splice(0, previousUrl.length - 1);
  previousUrl = [...previousUrl, navigationEnd.urlAfterRedirects];

  if (previousUrl.length === 1 && previousUrl[0] === route) {
    uniqueCorrelationId = this.generateUniqueId();
  } else if (previousUrl.length == 2 && previousUrl[1] === previousUrl[0]) {
    // Do nothing, return empty string
  } else if (previousUrl.length == 2 && previousUrl[1] != previousUrl[0]) {
    uniqueCorrelationId = this.generateUniqueId();
  }

  return uniqueCorrelationId;
}
```

In the converted code, the generateCorrelationId function returns a Promise that resolves to the unique correlation ID. The function waits for the first NavigationEnd event using the first() operator and then uses the resolved event to get the urlAfterRedirects property.

The splice and push methods for the previousUrl array are replaced with an assignment using the spread operator. Finally, the function returns the unique correlation ID that was generated based on the current and previous URLs.

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about this is to declare a `Subject` in shared.service.ts
and subscribe to in the component.service.ts

Once the logic in the `routerEvent` subscription is executed and the `uniqueCorrelationId` is finalised, then `subject.next(uniqueCorrelationId)` can be called and this will be read in the subscription callback block in the component.service.ts.

Refer Code below:

shared.service.ts:

```
export class Shared {
  private uuidEmitter: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>(); 

  getUuidEvent(): Observable<string> {
    return this.uuidEmitter.asObservable();
  }

  private sendUuid(uuid: string) {
    this.uuidEmitter.next(uuid);
  }

 //Your Code modified
  generateCorrelationId(routerEvent:any,route:string):any {
        let previousUrl:any =[];
        let uniqueCorrelationId = '';
        routerEvent.events
        .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
        .subscribe(({urlAfterRedirects}: NavigationEnd) => {
          previousUrl.splice(0,previousUrl.length-1)
          previousUrl = [...previousUrl, urlAfterRedirects];
          if(previousUrl.length === 1 && previousUrl[0]=== route) {
            uniqueCorrelationId = this.generateUniqueId();
          } else if(previousUrl.length == 2 && previousUrl[1] === previousUrl[0]) {
           uniqueCorrelationId = '';
          } else if(previousUrl.length == 2 && previousUrl[1] != previousUrl[0]) {
           uniqueCorrelationId = this.generateUniqueId();
          } else {
           uniqueCorrelationId = '';
          }
          this.sendUuid(uniqueCorrelationId);
        });
      }
}
```

component.service.ts:

```
constructor(private geneateUUid:GenerateUniqueIdService) {
    this.geneateUUid.getUuidEvent().subscribe(uuid:string => {
     let uniqueIdGeneration = uuid;
     console.log(uniqueIdGeneration,"uniqueIdGeneration")
    });
         
   this.geneateUUid.generateCorrelationId(this.router,'/findprofile');     
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all why `any` ?
The `generateCorrelationId` function is expected to return a value right? 'string' right?, but the subscribe method does not return anything. Therefore, the function will always return undefined.

I used to commit this mistake a lot, now I generally promisify my function.

```js
async generateCorrelationId(routerEvent:any,route:string): Promise<string> {
  let previousUrl:any = [];
  const uniqueCorrelationId = this.generateUniqueId();
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    routerEvent.events
      .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
      .subscribe(({urlAfterRedirects}: NavigationEnd) => {
        previousUrl.splice(0,previousUrl.length-1)
        previousUrl = [...previousUrl, urlAfterRedirects];
        if(previousUrl.length === 1 && previousUrl[0] === route) {
          resolve(uniqueCorrelationId);
        } else if(previousUrl.length == 2 && previousUrl[1] === previousUrl[0]) {
          resolve('');
        } else if(previousUrl.length == 2 && previousUrl[1] != previousUrl[0]) {
          resolve(this.generateUniqueId());
        } else {
          resolve(uniqueCorrelationId);
        }
      });
  });
}
```

PS. I am not angular expert, I looked at this from a JS POV and that is all. so someone else from angular POV might have a more streamlined answer.